# Read-only Oracle database as default

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-1.7

In the [Django 1.7 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#oracle-notes), it is stated that the Django user must have a number of CREATE privileges in order to use the new `python manage.py migrate` command. This obviously assumes that the Django project requires writing to the database. What if it doesn't? What if I don't want to use `migrate`?

I am starting a project where I will be using an Oracle database, but do not intend to give any write privileges to Django. I was surprised to see that I can't run `python manage.py runserver` even when the project is empty, and I just have a `settings.py` file. Instead, I get the following error message:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

How can I work around this?

**[EDIT]**
Also interesting, if I leave Oracle as the default database and head on to the shell, I can actually make queries normally.

**[EDIT 2]** Traceback...

```
[myproject]yourstruly@myserver /projects/django/myproject2 $ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1ce36e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 179, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 53, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 270, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 98, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/projects/.virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 916, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: OprojectsA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Migration means converting data from one schema to another. How could you do that without writing any data? Conversely, if you don't want to do that, why are you calling `migrate` in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert Exactly. I don't want to call it. I am assuming it is being called, though, for if I don't use the Oracle database as default, then I have no issues and it works as expected.

Comment: Can you paste the complete traceback that leads to the DatabaseError exception?

Comment: run `python manage.py migrate --fake` and then try it again.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I get the same error with `--fake`.

Comment: If your tables are already created, and you don't want django to create them - then you need to set [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#managed) to `False` for the model.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I already had `Meta: managed = False`.

Comment: Also Django is using DB for session handling. Just saying.